# Play two videos in same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

I search how I can play two videos in same time throughout the reading of the two videos.

For the moment, I recovered the current time of the two videos, I kept the smallest value, and I initialized the new value (the smallest) for the two videos.

Now I try to play them together and they run very slowly.

Thank's for helping me.

```
 var curtime1 = video1.currentTime;
 var curtime2 = video2.currentTime;
 var curtimefinal = Math.min(curtime1, curtime2);

 $('.time-slider').each(function ()
 {
     video1.currentTime = curtimefinal;
     video2.currentTime = curtimefinal;

     // video1.play(); I try it but the loading is so long
     // video2.play();
});
```

Comment: Can you create [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) or [bin](http://jsbin.com/?html,js,output) for this?

Comment: I create a fiiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nadir10/5djdkr7m/
In this exemple, the two videos runs fast because they are light, but the problem is real in my website.

Comment: I don't know how to help you. Maybe if it heavy, ut's slowly you know..

Comment: No problem, thank's